# What is the impact of C# closures on memory?

Tags: c#, lambda, closures

I have a class `Test` which holds two members, one (`arr`) which takes *a lot of memory* and the other (`b`) which doesn't:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test() {
        Arr = new int[100000000];
    }
    public bool B {get; private set;}
    public int[] Arr {get; private set;}
}
```

Later in my code, I want to store a lambda expression this way:

```
// `test` has been declared somewhere as an instance of Test
Action lambda = () => {
    if (test.B)
        // Do things
}
```

What will be the memory consumption of this closure?

**Will it hold the whole `Test` object in its environment, or only `Test.b`?**

Should I do instead:

```
var tmpB = test.B;
Action lambda = () => {
    if (tmpB)
        // Do things
}
```

Comment: not the answer, but what should `myInt = 1` do? lambdas don't take `ref` arguments, so this assignment will have no effect.

Comment: "Will it hold the whole Test object in its environment, or only Test.b?" Neither the one nor the other, it just holds a *reference* to `test`.

Comment: I did a minimal example and I forgot about ref, in my code it's a list I'll modify, let me correct that

Comment: It would really help if you'd post *actual code* rather than code that won't compile - and follow .NET naming conventions when writing that code, too.

Comment: @RenéVogt A lambda *can* take a `ref` argument, although that particular one doesn't.  It could be written `var lambda = (ref myInt) =>[...]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closure is going to store the value of the `test` variable, and the `test` variable is just a *reference* to an object of type `Test` elsewhere in memory, since it's not a `struct`, and that `Test` object doesn't actually have an integer array, it just has a reference to a large array stored in *yet another* location in memory.

Since you're holding onto a reference to that instance of `Test`, the object won't be eligible for garbage collection for as long as the closure isn't eligible for garbage collection.  If you pull the boolean value out of the `Test` object and close over *that*, as you showed, then you're no longer referencing the`Test` object.  If, as a result of that, nothing has access to the `Test` instance, or the contained array, then it would become eligible for garbage collection.  If there would still be other code that could access it, then that wouldn't be the case, and there'd be no benefit.

Comment: Dude, you just beat Jon Skeet. Congrats! ;)

Answer (score 7):

> Will it hold the whole Test object in its environment, or only Test.b?

Well, it will capture the *variable* `test` (by creating a separate class to contain that variable), which in turn has a value which is a reference to the instance of `Test`.

In other words, a method like this:

```
public Action Foo()
{
    Test test = new Test();
    Action printB = () => Console.WriteLine(test.b);
    return printB;
}
```

will be converted into something like this:

```
public Action Foo()
{
    CompiledGeneratedClass tmp = new CompilerGEneratedClass();
    tmp.test = new Test();
    Action printB = tmp.GeneratedMethod;
    return printB;
}

private class CompilerGeneratedClass
{
    public Test test;

    public void GeneratedMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test.b)
    }
}
```

So yes, if you don't want the delegate to effectively keep the instance of `Test` alive, you should pull out the value of the property first. Note that that has two semantic differences though:

- If the value of the property changes in the object, you won't see that in the delegate any more
- If the value of `test` itself changes (e.g. to refer to a different instance of `Test`) you won't see *that* in the delegate any more